# Auto comments on questions/answers

Tags: discussion, comments

I was having a look at the StackApps and found an [Auto Comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) script which also comes as a [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/se-autoreviewcomments/) extension.

I've installed this myself and used the pre-defined responses that were put together here:

[Standard responses to poor questions](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/standard-responses-to-poor-questions)

Just thought I would share it as it will come in very handy.

Comment: This will definitely come in handy. Thank you :)

Comment: a good find this one. I will check it when time allows.